# dedicated return line and recirculation pump

Tags: plumbing

I'm building a new home and I installed a dedicated return line for my water heater. The recirculation pump I have says it's not compatible with water heaters with heat traps. Does that only apply to recirculating configurations without recirculating lines?

Comment: I don't get the need for a down vote. The original post asked a legit question. I'm up voting the question.

Answer (score 4):

Some recirculation systems are based on gravity/thermal expansion effects that create a small pressure differential to keep hot water moving and recirculating through the pipes, from the hot water output back to the recirculation input.

This is a feature for comfort, and it comes at the expense of efficiency: hot water continually leaves the heater (albeit only a very low flow) and returns a bit less hot after having been cooled by the piping, all this while never having been used for washing etc...

This same gravity/thermal expansion effect that is exploited for recirculation can also cause an undesired flow of hot water out of the heater. Hot water leaves the heater and returns to it a bit less hot, all in the same outbound pipe. It's convection within a pipe, much like convection in a tall and narrow upright cylinder.

This undesired convection can be stopped by installing a P-trap or a nipple. Both create counter pressure to stop the flow: the P-trap by the gravitation and counter convection by the P shape of a section of pipe, and the nipple (a short piece of pipe with two male threaded ends) by the elasticity of a membrane or a ball inside it. It will take more pressure than that provided by convection to cause water to flow through them.

Two traps are shown here, one is based on a heavier than water ball, the other on a membrane.

[image]

When a faucet is opened, the much larger pressure from the water mains will easily push through the minor counter pressure, allowing water to flow as expected, but only when a fixture is open.

The counter pressure to prevent convection losses can form a problem for recirculation pumps that are designed for low flow at low differential pressures. Thus, a recirc pump that intends to pump water at a very low rate through a heater with nipples in the lines will need to be slightly more powerful than one rated for lines without such counter measures.

So if a pump is not rated for heat traps, it means it cannot overcome the heat trap's counter pressure. If the heater or its installation enable recirculation based on the same gravity principle, then the pump most likely can push through it, as it will aid the gravity induced flow, not counter it.

Comment: Very well written explanation!

Comment: The **hot** ball is heavier than water, the **cold** ball is lighter than water, to get into minor details.

Comment: @Ecnerwal, indeed. Would you happen to know what the design pressure difference is for these valves? I did some searching, even on supplier sites, and came out empty. I'd like to incorporate that into the answer. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I don't know that detail.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might just not understand how simple it is, you've either created a heat trap or you haven't.

Read this: https://sensibledigs.com/water-heater-heat-trap/

If that's not a part of your configuration, based on what you've written here - though there might be something you aren't mentioning that could be an issue - you are good to go.

if your water heater is heat trapped, then your recirc pump just won't recirc. It will sit there and burn out because there's no flow.

Comment: ok, so you know a general comment out into the ether goes under the question, right? Not under an answer...

Comment: Heres a refresher to answer your question.... https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-down "Downvote questions that don't show any research effort or don't contain enough information to be clear and answerable." ... https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-up "When should I vote up? Whenever you encounter a question, answer or comment that you feel is especially useful [...]."

Comment: WOW, there are too many 2 letter comments like DV, OP, UV, in your comments for me to even try to weigh in on answering this question. I am from the "old school" and do not understand all these 2 letter comments. Try actually writing out the English words so us old farts will understand what you are saying.  Geeezzz

Comment: DV means "down vote" UV means "up vote", OP means Original Poster.